# How to intercept a request after an observable does some work in Angular 5

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

Right before a request, I need to do some work in an observable and then let my intercept method handle the req. My interceptor class is something like this :

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ExampleHttpInterceptorProvider implements HttpInterceptor {

      constructor(private inj: Injector) { }

      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
        // here i want my observable that returns from doSomething() to work first
        // and then return next.handle(req);
      }
      doSomething(){
        return this.ExampleService.getDate().flatMap(
          (value) => {
            return this.http.post(SERVICE_URL+"value", this.getSomeParams(value));
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

I know it's not right but I think i need to to do something like

```
return this.doSomething().switchMap((r) => { return next.handle(req)});
```

I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: can you explain what is not working? Is the doSomething() not called? You approach seems reasonable to me. A detailed implementation of the doSomething method could help us figure out whats going on.

Comment: I edited doSomething() method. When I use it like that it becomes an infinite loop. Observable keeps repeating but cannot make the request work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `concat` to perform the request after `doSomething`.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return doSomething().concat(next.handle(req));
}

doSomething(){
    // returns an observable.
}
```

Comment: i tried this but doSometihng() didn't work. it returns an observable, needs subscription.

Comment: @Buzzinga What needs subscription? `defer()` doesn't and the `intercept()` method either.

Comment: doSomething() returns an observable.

Comment: Then you don't need `defer()` and just use `return doSomething().concat(next.handle(req))`